# GPU Memory is wrong in wmi

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, wmi

When I use wmi module in Python3, I found that the GPU Memory is wrong, My graphics card is RTX3070 Laptop with **8GB** RAM

Task manager and dxdiag.exe:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ezOH.jpg)

here is my code:

```
import wmi
wmi_o = wmi.WMI()
for gpu_item in wmi_o.Win32_VideoController():
    print(gpu_item)
```

and here is the output:

```
instance of Win32_VideoController
{
        AdapterCompatibility = "NVIDIA";
        AdapterDACType = "Integrated RAMDAC";
        AdapterRAM = 4293918720;
        Availability = 8;
        Caption = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU";
        ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
        ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
        CreationClassName = "Win32_VideoController";
        Description = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU";
        DeviceID = "VideoController2";
        DriverDate = "20210805000000.000000-000";
        DriverVersion = "30.0.14.7168";
        InfFilename = "oem51.inf";
        InfSection = "Section260";
        InstalledDisplayDrivers = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\nvlti.inf_amd64_2216898e7feeb52d\\nvldumdx.dll,C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\nvlti.inf_amd64_2216898e7feeb52d\\nvldumdx.dll,C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\nvlti.inf_amd64_2216898e7feeb52d\\nvldumdx.dll,C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\nvlti.inf_amd64_2216898e7feeb52d\\nvldumdx.dll";
        Monochrome = FALSE;
        Name = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU";
        PNPDeviceID = "PCI\\VEN_10DE&DEV_24DD&SUBSYS_3A4F17AA&REV_A1\\4&2CAE475F&0&0009";
        Status = "OK";
        SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
        SystemName = "#######";
        VideoArchitecture = 5;
        VideoMemoryType = 2;
        VideoProcessor = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU";
};
```

AdapterRAM is 4293918720(4GB), so how can I get the correct GPU Memory by using Python?And **how about AMD's graphics card?**
(nvidia-smi could be a solution, but AMD or Intel cannot use)

Comment: Does windows task manager, or running the "dxdiag" tool report your gfx card with 8GB RAM ? (There's RTX3070  GPUs out there with less than the max of 8GB RAM around)

Comment: Both task manager and dxdiag report 8GB.